# Recovering features names of StandardScaler().fit_transform() with sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

Edited from [a tutorial in Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/oneplustricks/time-series-analysis-xgboost/notebook), I try to run the code below and data ([available to download from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xc9my0ratl994gm/Aquifer_Petrignano.csv?dl=0)):

Code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # for plotting facilities
from datetime import datetime, date
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit, GridSearchCV
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error
import math
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.read_csv("./data/Aquifer_Petrignano.csv")

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format = '%d/%m/%Y')
df = df[df.Rainfall_Bastia_Umbra.notna()].reset_index(drop=True)

df = df.interpolate(method ='ffill')
df = df[['Date', 'Rainfall_Bastia_Umbra', 'Depth_to_Groundwater_P24', 'Depth_to_Groundwater_P25', 'Temperature_Bastia_Umbra', 'Temperature_Petrignano', 'Volume_C10_Petrignano', 'Hydrometry_Fiume_Chiascio_Petrignano']].resample('7D', on='Date').mean().reset_index(drop=False)

X = df.drop(['Depth_to_Groundwater_P24','Depth_to_Groundwater_P25','Date'], axis=1)
y1 = df.Depth_to_Groundwater_P24
y2 = df.Depth_to_Groundwater_P25

scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

model = xgb.XGBRegressor()
param_search = {'max_depth': range(1, 2, 2),
                'min_child_weight': range(1, 2, 2),
                'n_estimators' : [1000],
                'learning_rate' : [0.1]}

tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2)
gsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, cv=tscv,
                        param_grid=param_search)
gsearch.fit(X, y1)

xgb_grid = xgb.XGBRegressor(**gsearch.best_params_)
xgb_grid.fit(X, y1)

ax = xgb.plot_importance(xgb_grid)
ax.figure.tight_layout()
ax.figure.savefig('test.png')

y_val = y1[-80:]
X_val = X[-80:]

y_pred = xgb_grid.predict(X_val)
print(mean_absolute_error(y_val, y_pred))
print(math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_val, y_pred)))
```

I plotted a features importance figure whose original features names are hidden:

[image]

If I comment out these two lines:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

I get the output:

[image]

How could I use `scaler.fit_transform()` for `X` and get a feature importance plot with the original feature names?

Comment: What is your scikit-learn version?

Comment: It's `scikit-learn==0.22.2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind this is that `StandardScaler` returns a `numpy.ndarray` of your feature values (same shape as `pandas.DataFrame.values`, but not normalized) and you need to convert it back to `pandas.DataFrame` with the same column names.

Here's the part of your code that needs changing.

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X), columns=X.columns)
```

Comment: Thanks, do you mind test and edit the code in the question?

Comment: Edited the answer to fix your example. Its just the part that needs changing.

Answer (score 1):

You can now (since version 1.2.2) use the `set_output` method (see details [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_set_output.html))

```py
scaler = StandardScaler().set_output(transform="pandas")
```